# How to design this plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, naming-conventions, coding-style

I have a jQuery plugin that calls a callback.
 I'm passing in an object into the callback but there's one thing I don't know what to do about.

When the callback is called in one instance, it's returning from an ajax call and is passing the response into the object.
In  another case, it is passing a `jQuery` wrapped set of objects that are already loaded from ajax previously.

Should I call them both the same name, as they both represent the same content? Should they have different names as one is a string and the other is a `jQuery`?

What's the convention for passing a `jQuery` object in a parameter object? Do I call it `object.$response`? Or should I forget that idea and just leave both `object.response`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest, in order of preference :

- Normalise the parameter such that you pass a jQuery-wrapped set of objects in both cases, and name the argument `obj` or `jObj`
- Pass the response in one case and jQuery object in the other and name the argument `data`. Be sure to include explanatory comment(s) in the code.

In the second method you can branch inside the callback function as follows :

```
function(data) {
    if(data instanceof jQuery) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to pass a jQuery object in one case, and need to in another. So basically options 2? Are there any plugins that do this?

Comment: I don't think a plugin is the way ahead. Addition to the answer above shows you how to branch according to whether or not a jQuery object is passed.